# Setting SelectedValue in DropDownList inside Repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How I've made this work is entirely too ugly so i know i must be missing something..
Tell me how to set the SelectedValue of the DDL in a better way.
I've tried setting the SelectedValue in the DropDownList tag and using Eval("b.codeID") in the OnDataBound Event which gives me an "Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control." error.
Code below is what works now..What i dont like about it is having to put a asp:Label bound to b.CatID just to reference it in the OnDataBound event to use it in the For Each loop. I should be able to get the value of eval("b.CodeID") in a more elegant way.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptLabor" runat="server" OnItemCommand="button_click" OnItemDataBound="rptLaborDataBound">
 <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLaborCodeEdit" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
 <asp:Label ID="lblddlLaborCodeEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "b.catid")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label></td>

Sub rptLaborDataBound(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs)
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
        Dim ddlLaborCode As DropDownList = CType(e.Item.FindControl("ddlLaborCodeEdit"), DropDownList)
        Dim lblLaborCode As Label = CType(e.Item.FindControl("lblddlLaborCodeEdit"), Label)

            SetddlLaborBillCode(ddlLaborCode)


        For Each item As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem In ddlLaborCode.Items
            If item.Value = lblLaborCode.Text Then
                item.Selected = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

Protected Sub SetddlLaborBillCode(ByVal ddl As DropDownList)
    Dim db As New TtCSIDataContext
    Dim sel = (From a In db.tblBillCodesByClients _
              Where a.ClientID = ddlClient.Text And a.Grp = "LAB" _
              Select a.CodeID, Code = a.Code & " | " & a.CodeDescr).ToList

    ddl.DataSource = sel
    ddl.DataTextField = "Code"
    ddl.DataValueField = "CodeID"
    ddl.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you're saying now about the issue with binding from the markup.  Well, hopefully I can at least help clean up your current approach.

I dropped the Label, and just grab the value of "b.catid" from the `e.Item.DataItem` property in the ItemDataBound event.

Also, since you're confident that the value of "b.catid" will be in the list of values in your DropDownList, you can just set the SelectedValue directly (rather than looping through the items).

Markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptLabor" runat="server" OnItemCommand="button_click" 
    OnItemDataBound="rptLaborDataBound">
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLaborCodeEdit" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
```

VB.NET code:

```
Sub rptLaborDataBound(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs)

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
        Dim ddlLaborCode As DropDownList = CType(e.Item.FindControl("ddlLaborCodeEdit"), DropDownList)
        Dim catIDCode As String = CType(e.Item.DataItem("b.catid"), String)

        SetddlLaborBillCode(ddlLaborCode)       
        ddlLaborCode.SelectedValue = catIDCode

    ...
```

Comment: You would think so but since the dropdown doesn't get databound until the repeater OnDataBound event, i get the "'ddlLaborCodeEdit' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value" error

Comment: Ah, my bad @Paul.  I've updated my answer with something that's hopefully a little cleaner.  It uses the `e.Item.DataItem` property, which you can use to grab the "back end" values being bound to this RepeaterItem.

Comment: @Paul One thing I was confused about: the body of your question mentions "b.codeID", but the code only references "b.catid".  You can use that `DataItem` object to grab either value, but I stuck with "b.catid", since that's what was in your code already.

Comment: That didn't work but put me on the right track... Dim catIDCode As String = CType(e.Item.DataItem("b.catid"), String) threw a "No default member found for type 'VB$AnonymousType_10" error. BUT "Dim catIDCode As String = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "b.catid")" works as expected. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help!  I rarely use VB.NET, but I wonder if it was just the wonky string casting that caused the error in the first place.  What if you did  `Dim catIDCode As String = e.Item.DataItem("b.catid").ToString()`?  I just wouldn't expect you to have to use `DataBinder.Eval` in codebehind (I never have).